# How can I use the first entry of a JSON data array

Tags: javascript, json

I got this JSON as data:

```
data = {"livemode":false,"pending":
[{"amount":0,"currency":"jpy"},{"amount":8121,"currency":"usd"}],
"available":   
[{"amount":-400,"currency":"jpy"},{"amount":99601,"currency":"usd"}]}
```

now I want to convert this into a more readable text something like this:

```
"Pending :" + "\n" + "Amount :" + data.pending[0].amount + "\n" + data.pending[0].currency;
```

So I want to give back the amount of 0 with the currency of jpy but all I get is an Error or undefined, what I'm doing wrong here?

```
onRetrieveBalancePressed : function() {
        var that = this;
            jQuery.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                contentType : "application/json",
                url : "https:" + "/retrieve",
                processData: true,
                dataType : "text",
                async: false,

                success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        var sResult = "Balance successfully retrieved! \n"
                    +"Pending :" + "\n"
                    +"livemode :" + data.pending[0].amount + "\n"

                    +"Currency : " + data.pending[0].currency;
```

Comment: @ar4ers  sorry I'm working on javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First just try to convert your data to JSON using 
`var obj = JSON.parse(data);`

then try to get data from obj.

In case of jquery, you can also try this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: sorry Mate, was a copy failure by me, in my code I don't have quotes there, so its still not working

Comment: I added above my full code of that function that is called, I get the error Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a JSONObject and put data in that obj then you can work more easily

Comment: sorry forgot to use the right tags I'm working with javascript

Comment: ann ok i don't know very well js